# How to wrap python argument values in quotes?

Tags: python

I am trying to construct a python command as follows ,issue is that some of the arguments values have spaces and the script is failing to run later,
options `-at` and `-m` in the below command have spaces for the values passed to these arguments,I want to wrap these values to add quotes (`""`)?how can I do that?

```
change=12345
source_milestone="source1 milestone"
target_milestone="target1 milestone"
cmd =  r'python ./script.py -u username -rl {} -ra adar.py -d 1234567 -at CLONED_FROM_{} -m {} -r AUTOMATION'.format(change,source_milestone.upper(),str(target_milestone))

print cmd
```

OUTPUT:-

```
python ./script.py -u username -rl 12345 -ra adar.py -d 1234567 -at CLONED_FROM_SOURCE1 MILESTONE -m target1 milestone -r AUTOMATION
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT:-**NOTICE the quotes("") around `-at` and `-m`**

```
python ./script.py -u username -rl 12345 -ra adar.py -d 1234567 -at "CLONED_FROM_SOURCE1 MILESTONE" -m "target1 milestone" -r AUTOMATION
```

Comment: Use single quotes in the python code and double quotes around the arguments.

Comment: yea, why not just do this `cmd =  r'python ./script.py -u username -rl "{}" -ra adar.py -d 1234567 -at CLONED_FROM_{} -m "{}" -r AUTOMATION'.format(change,source_milestone.upper(),str(target_milestone))
`

Comment: Why are you trying, *in Python*, to construct a command line string to execute a Python script? Even if you absolutely must launch a Python script from another Python script, you should use something like [`subprocess.run`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) instead of this manual quoting.

Comment: Why not just use a list of arguments so that you don't need to worry about quoting at all?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams - Can you please be more specific on how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Since your cmd string is created with single quotes, you can insert double quotes into it wherever you want. Just put them around the {}.

```
var = 'variable with spaces'
cmd = r'python ./script.py -u username -rl "{}"'.format(var)

print(cmd)

python ./script.py -u username -rl "variable with spaces"
```